# How can I return to a HTML page from a WebFlux Handler

Tags: kotlin, routes, spring-webflux

I have a webflux web application.  I am trying to forward to a html page once the handler has finished.  The code I have is as follows.  Is this easy to do?

Router

```
@Configuration
class WebRouter(val handler: Handler) {

    @Bean
    fun route() = router {
        accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
        GET("/fixing_check", handler::check_fixing).also { GET("/best", handler::anotherHandler) }
        }
    }

}
```

Handler

```
fun check_fixing (serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse>{
        .....
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(
            Flux.fromStream(tocList.stream()).log(), FixingData::class.java
    )
}
```

Configuration for static data

```
@Configuration
class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun resRouter() = resources("/**", ClassPathResource("static/"))

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your router configurations to redirect upon finishing your handler using `then()` operator:

```
@Configuration
class WebRouter(val handler: Handler) {

  @Bean
  fun route() = router {
    accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
      GET("/fixing_check") { _ -> handler::check_fixing.then(ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/best")).build()) } }
      GET("/best") { _ -> handler::anotherHandler }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So this will forward me to a URI called best which would then kick off another handler.  I want to forward to a html page though?  Or have I missed something.

Comment: You can redirect to any URL you want other than best. Or else you can return HTML from `then()` block

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update above.  I came to a conclusion on this with the following code:

```
@Component
class Handler {

    val testList = listOf("String1", "String2", "String3")

    fun checkSomething(severRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(
                Flux.fromIterable(testList), String::class.java
        ).then(ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI("/test_thymeleaf.html")).build())
    }

}
```

The handler now forwards to a html page!  That's great.

Thanks for your helps